# URL obsfucation?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need to have all links to mp3 files on a Wordpress site hidden from the user without being hidden from the mp3 player I have set up on the page to play them. (Initial defense against unauthorized downloads.)

I would also like to remove the "wp-" prefix on all wordpress folder names (wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes) in a way that will not break future updates to Wordpress.

Best if both of these tasks can be done without renaming the actual directory and instead using PHP, .htaccess, Javascript, or something else to "mask" the true url.

Thanks!

Comment: If his/her browser plays it, the user already downloaded it.

Comment: geez for the next question will just create a brand new account

Comment: That's exactly the *wrong* response to the request.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure as to how well you will be able to mask anything using JavaScript. A better solution would be to create a PHP Script that would serve your mp3 files based on whether a user is authenticated or something. That way you could at least store the mp3 files one folder up from your web root and away from people trying to download them using urls.